# decode Base64 from shell

Tags: bash, shell, awk, base64, decode

Help if possible,please.
I want to reconstruct the file try.txt

try.txt contains:

```
uid: random1
sn: 8

uid: random2
sn:: SGVsbG8sIFdvcmxkIQo=
```

to this:

```
random1 8
random2 Hello, World!
```

the problem is in Base64. Whats the best and possible way to decode it?

1) Search though try.txt line by line and decode on matching string
Is this possible to do with awk or is this wishful thinking?
This doesn't work -> `cat try.txt |  awk '{if ($1 == "sn::") base64 -d $2'`

2) search through sn.txt line by line and decode on matching string

```
path=/dev/shm
uidf=$path/uid.txt
snf=$path/sn.txt
ff=$path/ff.txt
```

some code to search through $snf for different Base64 encoded text
could you help with this?
2a)
    cat try.txt |  grep -v dn: | awk '/uid/ {print $2}' > $uidf
    cat try.txt |  grep -v dn: | awk '/sn/ {print $2}' > $snf

here some code to search for base64 encoded string and decode it

```
paste $uidf $snf | awk '{print $1,$2}' > $ff
```

2b)
    cat try.txt |  grep -v dn: | awk '{print}'

```
case "$string" in
    "sn::" ) base64 -d $string;;
esac
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

this one-liner can give what you want:

```
awk -v RS="" '$3=="sn::"{"base64 -d<<< \""$4"\""|getline $4}{print $2,$4}' file
```

In the command above `getline` was used for getting output from an external cmd (base64).

test with your file:

```
kent$  cat f
uid: random1
sn: 8

uid: random2
sn:: SGVsbG8sIFdvcmxkIQo=

kent$  awk -v RS="" '$3=="sn::"{"base64 -d<<< \""$4"\""|getline $4}{print $2,$4}' f
random1 8
random2 Hello, World!
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for helping. It doesn't work though. output: `random1 8
sh: 1: Syntax error: redirection unexpected
random2 SGVsbG8sIFdvcmxkIQo=`

Comment: @user2707431 you copied my command and with your example file?

Comment: i did, copied, wrote it deosn't work. i found out that ubuntu is using dash  by default but even calling from bash doesn't work, maybe its just ubuntu problems =( or are there some extensions to bash?

Comment: @user2707431 I don't know ubuntu. I tested that line under zsh and bash, worked. you tagged question as bash, then don't test it with dash. btw, better use `gnu awk (gawk)`

Comment: @user2707431 I don't think it is distro problem. I am using archlinux. is the content of your file **exactly** same as that in your question? the `try.txt` also report your awk version pls

Comment: awk has GNU Awk 3.1.8

Comment: @user2707431 try this line: `awk -v RS="" '$3=="sn::"{"echo \""$4"\"|base64 -d"|getline $4}{print $2,$4}' f` it used a pipe instead of `<<<`. tested here with zsh/bash.

Comment: FYI there's nothing gawk-specific about either solution, it'll work with any modern awk.

Answer (score 0):

Try this out:

```
awk '/^uid: /{printf $2" "}/^sn: /{print $2}/^sn:: /{print $2|"base64 --decode"}'
```

Answer (score -3):

In your fist variant:

```
cat try.txt | awk '{if ($1 == "sn::") base64 -d $2'
```

use `substr(index($0, $2))` instead of `$2`.

You also need an "else" for non-matching lines.

Comment: This answer makes absolutely no sense.

Comment: you are right about the substr() part, but I was trying to point out that he is not covering the case for non-matching lines.

Here is my second shot: 

cat file | awk '{if ($1 == "sn::") {system("echo " $2 "| base64 -d")} else print $0}' > output.txt

Comment: @user3012345 Your way to convert from Base64 works as well. Thank you all people.